# How can I add/remove an item from an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, element

What method can I use in adding or removing an element from my array.
Is there a method for this?
Plus, one that resizes the array automatically in cases when an element is deleted to prevent the default "0" from occupying that space.

Comment: Arrays are immutable, so you will have to do the resizing yourself. True deletion also won't be possible without manual resizing. Have you considered using an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Tried using some search engine?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have those methods for arrays but you can use `ArrayList` instead. Code example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("str 1");
list.add("str 2");
list.add(0,"str 3"); // Add 3 on position 0
list.remove(1); // remove item on position 1
list.remove("str 2"); // remove first occurrence of str 2
```

But you can't use primitive type directly as in arrays, if you want `ArrayList` of int then you will use Integer class which acts as wrapper for primitive type -
 `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, didn't want to say it that way, I meant that there are not such methods that OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

So you can't perform all the actions that you mentioned above using arrays.

You might look into using `ArrayList` class in java. It has in built remove libraries as well.

Check this link out - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)